# Tomcat 7 common WEB-INF for global UrlRewriteFilter

Tags: tomcat7, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter, web-inf

I have a Tomcat7 webserver running with a few apps and an UrlRewriteFilter (org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter) which needs to be configured with an xml-file. This xml file must live within the WEB-INF directory of an app (because the confPath of the UrlRewriteFilter is always relative to the root of WEB-INF).

I want the RewriteFilter for ALL the apps and I don't want a copy of the urlrewrite.xml in each apps WEB-INF folder.

Is there something like a global WEB-INF folder for tomcat? Or another way to do a UrlRewrite for all the apps?